# snmptt cannot load PERL module

Tags: centos, perl

CentOS 7
I cannot move forward with starting snmptt. I use it to translate traps into nagios. I have been poking around with my system and this issue occured after I make uninstalled extra net-snmp installation from tarball. I have the yum installation.

The snmptt status output:

```
Compilation failed in require at (eval 12) line 1.
died at /usr/sbin/snmptt line 426
Could not load the Perl module SNMP!
```

yum perl packages installed

```
[root@sup-han-vrt perl5]# yum list installed | grep net-snmp-perl
net-snmp-perl.x86_64                  1:5.7.2-24.el7_2.1       @base
[root@sup-han-vrt perl5]# yum list installed | grep perl-Net-SNMP
perl-Net-SNMP.noarch                  6.0.1-7.el7              @epel
```

the PERL @INC

```
env -i perl -V
  @INC:
/usr/local/lib64/perl5
/usr/local/share/perl5
/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl
/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl
/usr/lib64/perl5
/usr/share/perl5
```

The SNMP.pm is in both lib64 dirs so not sure what the problem is. Please help.

Comment: I started snmptt with most debug info and it complains about missing libnetsnmp.so.30, that indeed is no longer on the system.Can't load '/usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/NetSNMP/default_store/default_store.so' for module NetSNMP::default_store: libnetsnmp.so.30: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory at /usr/lib64/perl5/DynaLoader.pm line 190.

Comment: `yum install perl-Net-SNMP`

Comment: I uninstalled the perl-Net-SNMP with yum but the `/usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/NetSNMP/` and further is still intact. Is that a relic from some old bodged install?

Comment: So after some wondering around and checking the makefile of the tarball that I previously had installed, the NetSNMP failing is from the tarball installation. What should I do now to get rid of the perl modules it installed?

Comment: Thanks for help thrig, I had to get rid of whole perl5 folder in `/usr/local/lib64` and it is working now. Can you post reply so I can flag it as solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Can't load `lib.../perl5/.../*.so`" indicates that an XS module (that is, not a pure Perl module, but one with C includes) is not installed correctly. In this case, on RedHat, the `/usr/local` tree indicates something outside of the vendor managed space, so a custom install of some sort. Solutions include:

- Nuke the custom install and instead use the vendor packages. Probably the best option, as the required RPMs can be specified in a KickStart file or other package manifest.
- Reinstall the custom modules. This is typically more work, but may be necessary should the vendor packages be hopelessly out of date or otherwise buggy. This should ideally not be done to a common directory such as `/usr/local`, but rather a custom tree, e.g. with a modern Perl installed via [Perl::Build](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl::Build), or to a special [local::lib](https://metacpan.org/pod/local::lib) module directory for the application or service.